# find all method invocations

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I using eclipse *Java search* find all calls of methods that are declared in specific class?

I tried `p1.p2.p3.MyClass.*` but this search string finds `equals`, `getClass` calls which is not necessary. I only need to find methods that are declared explicitly in `p1.p2.p3.MyClass`.

Comment: Doesn't `findUsages` work for you? Sure it might find some other methods as well but at least those are delcared a "potential match".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found how it can be done using Java search. I have filtered out overrode methods from search result and got only methods defined in type.

Thank you all for your time spent on this question nevertheless :)

Comment: Please explain how you did it.

Answer (score 2):

If you select the method pressing `CRTL ALT H` you can see the call hierarchy and configure its view.

In the outline view you can select multiple methods, then right button and open in call hierarchy. Again `CRTL ALT H`  .

You can find references to a class by selecting the class name and `CRTL SHIFT G` (references).

Comment: That works only for one method. I need to find all methods, declared in a specific class.

Answer (score 2):

Select the method name and hit CTRL-SHIFT-G, which searches for all references to this method.

If you want to find all of the usages of all of the methods, you can't do that, but you can find all usages of the class, by selecting the class name and doing CTRL-SHIFT-G.

Comment: That works only for one method. I need to find all methods, declared in a specific class.

Comment: Edited to add find usages of a class.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the method that you want to find. Right click and select the option to see all references.

Eclipse is amazing for this. It should show all references in a panel of results